# How does a Yardrat know that Vegeta became faster than Goku?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super, dragon-ball-manga

In Dragon Ball Super manga #55,

> A Yardrat who's teaching Vegeta techniques, says he's faster than Goku

Is Goku supposed to be traveling to Yardrat often or something? How does a Yardrat know that Vegeta became faster than Goku?

Answer (score 1):

**This is a mistranslation.**

The official translation ([found on Mangaplus](https://mangaplus.shueisha.co.jp/viewer/1006078), page 6) clearly says (in Elder Pybara's words) :

> "Your spirit is now more polished than Goku's, and you managed it in no time."

Elder Pybara was comparing their respective trainings' duration. As stated within Dragon Ball Super (*chapter 53, page 48*), Goku spent 150 days meditating upon a training spire and Vegeta had to achieve comparable results in only 10 days. Elder Pybara's reaction clearly indicates that Vegeta did train quite faster.